# Cannot parse nodejs output of JSON.stringify in java using jackson lib

Tags: java, json, node.js

Below string is the output that I am getting from node js which uses json.stringify method. This string is not a proper java string thus is not parseable. How to parse it in java? I am using Jackson lib for Json support.

```
{"m":"data","dID":"11:22:33:44:55:66","t":"Thu, 11 Feb 2016 05:34:52 GMT","d":[{"sID":"hydrogen","d1":44.27927702199668,"d2":0.26740958681330085,"d3":10.4},{"sID":"gps","d1":-9.007042,"d2":53.292506,"d3":63}]}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Create a POJO with your json fields and use `ObjectMapper.readValue()` method

Comment: why it's not a proper string? - can't see anything problematic

Comment: @Daniel in java it gives compilation error. Problem with double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

First create your POJOs:

```
public class MyFirstClass {

    private String m;
    private String dID;
    private String t;
    private List<MySecondClass>;

    //getters and setters

}

public class MySecondClass {

    private String sID;
    private double d1;
    private double d2;
    private double d3;

    //getters and setters  

}
```

And then deserialize your json:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyFirstClass response = mapper.readValue(jsonStringResponse, MyFirstClass.class);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I cant create POJO as the Json string is dynamic in nature and the MySecondClass class, as per ur post can have multiple device, d1,d2,d3....dn.

Comment: Then, you have to do it manually. But, I recommend to change your response json to be a list of devices, instead of d1 property, d2 property, d3 property... and so on, instead.

Answer (score 0):

You already have jackson just create POJO and annotate its member to the json string as follows

```
class C{
    @JsonProperty("m")
    private String m; 
    /*getter, setter */
}
```